# Why does `wget` download index.html instead of a direct file?

Tags: wget

I'm just trying to download this, but it always redirect to the main page and in the end just download the index.html file, not the file I'm trying to download:

http://tweaking.com/files/setups/tweaking.com_windows_repair_aio.zip

Do you guys know how to download it correctly? I used --user-agent="firefox+linux, IE+windows, (anything you can think of)" but it doesn't work.

This is the output, is the same with `--user-agent` enabled:

```
jaheaga@jaheaga:~$ wget  http://www.tweaking.com/files/setups /tweaking.com_windows_repair_aio.zip--2012-04-13 19:40:07--  http://www.tweaking.com/files/setups/tweaking.com_windows_repair_aio.zip
Resolviendo www.tweaking.com... 199.119.100.39
Conectando con www.tweaking.com[199.119.100.39]:80... conectado.
Petición HTTP enviada, esperando respuesta... 302 Found
Ubicación: http://tweaking.com [siguiente]
--2012-04-13 19:40:08--  http://tweaking.com/
Resolviendo tweaking.com... 199.119.100.39
Reutilizando la conexión con www.tweaking.com:80.
Petición HTTP enviada, esperando respuesta... 302 Moved Temporarily
Ubicación: http://www.tweaking.com [siguiente]
--2012-04-13 19:40:08--  http://www.tweaking.com/
Reutilizando la conexión con www.tweaking.com:80.
Petición HTTP enviada, esperando respuesta... 200 OK
Longitud: no especificado [text/html]
Grabando a: “tweaking.com_windows_repair_aio.zip.1”

    [ <=>                                                                            ]     46.913       234K/s   en 0,2s    

2012-04-13 19:40:09 (234 KB/s) - “tweaking.com_windows_repair_aio.zip.1” guardado [46913]
```

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: The link is not working at all. At least, for me. How about uploading it to somewhere? And use the direct link from there?

Comment: it gives me the main page, but go to http://tweaking.com/files/setups/ and you can check it, weird behavior of that link

Comment: BTW: I am curious. What's the reason for downloading the file with `wget` instead of inside the browser? I mean you definitely used a browser to find the download url :)

Comment: duty noted, is a batch script I use to fix really broken windows computers.

Comment: Ah ok, makes sense. And the question looks much better now, thanks. (Removed my comment).

Comment: In case you would like to have English output next time: Just execute `export LANGUAGE=en_US:en LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8` once before all the other commands, and they put out everything in (US) English with US number/date formats etc. (This setting is only for the current shell (and subshells) and everything is back to normal, when you close it and/or open another one)

Answer (score 10):

The user-agent is a good start, but not sufficient in that case. Another HTTP header value that is often checked for is 'Referer' [sic!]. See [Wikipedia: HTTP Referer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer).

wget has a `--referer=url` option to specify the referring page. Analysing the traffic for a successful download in `Wireshark` shows that it used following request from a testing system of mine:

```
GET /files/setups/tweaking.com_windows_repair_aio.zip HTTP/1.1
Host: www.tweaking.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:11.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/11.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-gb,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://www.tweaking.com/content/page/windows_repair_all_in_one.html
```

For this case it even seems you don't need to fake an `User-Agent`.

```
wget --referer=http://www.tweaking.com/content/page/windows_repair_all_in_one.html  http://www.tweaking.com/files/setups/tweaking.com_windows_repair_aio.zip
```

Does the trick.